# Fastest way to run an algorithm on several arguments, having run it in the past, after a change to one variable

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, optimization, websocket

The best way I can think to explain my question is with the following example. Note that "a conditional returning True" is actually a response from an asynchronous websocket.

Say, as a `while True` loop is running, there is a variable `x` assigned to a list of 15 dicts, each dict having 5 key/value pairs, with each pair having been chosen randomly from a dict `y` of 26 key/value pairs, where each key is a letter of the alphabet. It is known that none of the values of the dicts in `x` sum to > 50.

Say some some conditional in the `while True` loop turns true, and the value for key `a` in `y` is now 30. Besides brute forcing, is there any faster way to check if the values of any dict in `x` now sum to > 50, accounting for the change to `a`?

Note: I am looking for a solution that applies to all keys in `y`, not just `a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that by "there is a variable x assigned to a list of 15 dicts, each dict having 5 key/value pairs", you mean "there a list of 15 dicts, each dict having 5 key/value pairs, assigned to a variable x".

If the values of the key/values are repeatedly subject to change, while the keys for each dict remain the same, then the simplest way is probably to keep track of the sum of each dict, and change them as the value changes. And it's probably faster to "transpose" the dicts, so to speak, so that instead of having for each dict seeing what keys it is in, you have that for each key, you store what dicts it is in. For example:

```
inclusions = {key: 
    [index for index in range(len(x)) if key in x[index].keys()]
    for key in y.keys()}
#inclusions is a dictionary is which each key is a key from y
#and each value is a list of dictionaries in x
#that contain that key

sums = [sum(x[i].values() for i in range(len(x)))]
#sums is a list of sums of the corresponding dicts in x
#i.e. the nth value of sums is the sum of the values in x[n]

while True:
    # y[a] changes from old_value to new_value
    diff = new_value-old_value
    for index in inclusions[a]:
        sums[index] += diff
    #you can now test for >50
    #e.g. any([value > 50 for value in sums])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store how much "space" every dict still has left.

Say `dict1` sums `42`, you would store `8`.

Now, every time you change some value in `y`, you need to know by how much you've changed. If the value was `10` and now is `22`, you would see that `12` is bigger than `8`, in other words, `dict1` sums more than 50...

Remember to update how much every dict still has left! If you changed `10` to `12`, you will note that `2` is less than `8`, meaning that `dict1` still sums less than `50` after the change in `y`, bu know it only has `6`...

Comment: But `dict1` may not contain the changed element in `y`. Each dict in `x` contains 5 key/ value pairs out of the possible 26 in `y`.

Comment: store an additional dict, with the count of every key from `y` that is present in `dict1`